# Adjusting spec/destination in ArgoCD Application with kustomize

Tags: openshift, devops, kustomize, argocd

I am relatively new to kustomize and am trying to work out how I can use it to adjust the destination namespace/server in a argocd Application resource.

The resource is defined as below:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: application-1
  namespace: openshift-gitops
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: argo-app
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
  project: default
  source:
    path: .
    targetRevision: master
    repoURL: git@github.com:organization/example.git
  syncPolicy:
    automated:
      prune: true
      selfHeal: true
```

I want to adjust the destination namespace and the destination server. I need to do this without it changing the application resource namespace which needs to remain in openshift-gitops.

I am having difficulty with this. I have tried a patch method and a CRD but I lack the technical knowledge to implement either of these correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not answering your question but have you looked at Argo ApplicationSet which may remove the need for Kustomize at all here.